# Getting this uncaught typeerror when importing ReactDayPicker

Tags: react-day-picker

I'm simply importing at the top of my file as so:

```
import DayPicker from 'react-day-picker'
```

And then I'm getting this error in my console and can't seem to figure it out.

```
Weekdays.js?f84d:23 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
    at _inherits (Weekdays.js?f84d:23)
    at eval (Weekdays.js?f84d:26)
    at eval (Weekdays.js?f84d:77)
    at Object../node_modules/react-day-picker/lib/src/Weekdays.js (person.js:4066)
    at __webpack_require__ (common.js:694)
    at fn (common.js:115)
    at eval (Month.js?f52a:17)
    at Object../node_modules/react-day-picker/lib/src/Month.js (person.js:4014)
    at __webpack_require__ (common.js:694)
    at fn (common.js:115)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on React v0.14.8 and I'm getting the same error. In v6.0.0 of react-day-picker, some components were converted to use React.PureComponent (which was introduced in React v15.3.0). I believe this is why we're getting that error because our versions of React doesn't have React.PureComponent. The fix would be to upgrade your React to v15.3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-day-picker v6.0, try to upgrade to v6.2 where the PureComponent has been replaced by `shouldComponentUpdate`. This should keep compatibility with React 0.14+